Do I have a right to salary information for all categories of employees?
The EU directive on pay transparency gives employees the right to information on certain pay-related topics, excerpt from the link:

Once in the role, workers will be entitled to ask their employers for information about:

average pay levels, broken down by sex, for categories of employees doing the same work or work of equal value


Does this mean I will be given the "average pay levels" for "categories determined by work of equal value" or will I be given the "average pay levels" for "the categories of employees similar to my own"? The intention seems to be the latter, but in light of transparency, I'd somehow not be surprised with the former.

Is this about Directive 2023/970? Art 7(1) only refers to "information on their individual pay level and the average pay levels, broken down by sex, for categories of workers performing the same work as them or work of equal value to theirs". This seems to be a narrow right intended to provide only three numbers: own pay, average male pay in comparable roles, average female pay in comparable roles. What is comparable is explained a bit in Art 19.

The basic idea is that you're entitled to enough information to determine if you're being paid above or below average for what you do. So you only need the statistics for other workers in the same role.

Doesn't 'EU directive' also imply that this has no legal power on its own but it rather means EU member countries are required to enact laws that realize this directive? After they did that one could check for the details in these laws and the details may depend on the country.

@amon: I think the words "to theirs" answers the question.
